# Limit cart to only use 1 coupon - woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

how can I limit my coupon so a customer won't be able to use multiple coupon on the same checkout?

I'm using WP Woocommerce 4.2.2

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you show some code where you are having the problem?

Comment: I have the problem fx. when a customer uses 3 coupons of 40% of the basket (each) - then the items will be 'free'.

Comment: Check out the [Woocommerce documentation on usage restriction](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/coupon-management/#section-3)

Comment: Thank you @Harben - i've been struggling with this for quite a while now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by activating the option **Individual use only**, at the coupon editing form. This will block the use of additional coupons.

For more information check [the official documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/coupon-management/#section-3).

Comment: Anyway to do this using PHP code rather than the setting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53251149/8391466

Answer (score 0):

The following code will remove the first applied coupon, if customer applies another coupon code, so there will be only one applied coupon in cart *(the last applied coupon)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'one_applied_coupon_only', 10, 1 );
function one_applied_coupon_only( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // For more than 1 applied coupons only
    if (  sizeof($cart->get_applied_coupons()) > 1 && $coupons = $cart->get_applied_coupons() ){
        // Remove the first applied coupon keeping only the last appield coupon
        $cart->remove_coupon( reset($coupons) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.